# SQLite fails to read row 0

Tags: android, sqlite

So I am trying to return a string from an SQLite database - I've seen a few examples on here but no matter what I try it still crashes saying

```
Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
```

To assign the result to a string I am using

```
String email = db.GetEmail();
```

The getEmail() function is as follows:

```
public String GetEmail(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String QueryText = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QueryText,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    if(cursor.isFirst()){
        String result = cursor.getString(1);
    return result;  
    }else{
        return "FALSE";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message explain the problem.

There is one column and column indices are 0-based.
Try:

```
String result = cursor.getString(0); /* first column */
```

Comment: The other problem is that when I assign it to a String it prints out "null"